# how to write number of days in c#

Tags: c#, numbers, days

how can I write program in c# that show the number of the day

for example :

I ask a user to type a day and he write Monday and I want to show him 2

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: google: C# day of week| First entry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Day of the week or day of the month? What is the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Definition:

```
namespace System
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [Serializable, ComVisible(true), __DynamicallyInvokable]
    public enum DayOfWeek
    {
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        Friday = 5,
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        Monday = 1,
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        Saturday = 6,
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        Sunday = 0,
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        Thursday = 4,
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        Tuesday = 2,
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        Wednesday = 3
    }
}
```

Example:

```
// For your case Monday == 2
int todayDayOfWeekNumber = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + 1;
```

Comment: `DayOfWeek` return the name of the day. Not a number.

Comment: Voting is anonymous...

Comment: @RagingBull except if it is casted in `int`. `If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday).`

Comment: @RagingBull It also returns a number, you have to just cast it.

Comment: @dyatchenko: Yup, removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(System.DateTime.Now.Day) % 7;     //will return integer 2 for Monday
```

Example:

```
DateTime inputDate = System.DateTime.Now;
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(((inputDate.Day)%7).ToString());
```

**OR:**

Using `DayOfWeek` (just like dyatchenko mentioned):

```
((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + 1)
```

`DayOfWeek` starts from Sunday (with 0). So if you want to get 2 for Monday, just add 1.

Comment: `value ranges from zero (which indicates DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx